# How to programmatically fetch LearnDash Quiz Statistics for Modal Display

Tags: php, wordpress, learndash

I'm trying to programmatically populate a modal with the quiz statistics form for a given quiz attempt (the one that shows on the quiz attempt statistics modal) and I was under the impression that I could use the

```
WpProQuiz_Controller_Statistics();
```

Along with `ajaxLoadStatisticUser($user_data, '');`

Where user_data was the statistics_ref ID, the userID of the student and a nonce (created as you can see below).

But all I get in the response is CSS code.

Can any developers who are familiar with LearnDash point me in the right direction?

```
if ($ref_id && $user_id) {
 $statisticController = new WpProQuiz_Controller_Statistics();
 
 $user_data = array(
 'refId' => $ref_id,
 'userId' => $user_id,
                'statistic_nonce' => esc_attr(wp_create_nonce('statistic_nonce_' . $ref_id . '_' . get_current_user_id() . '_' . $user_id))
 );
 $result = $statisticController->ajaxLoadStatisticUser($user_data, '');
 error_log(print_r($result, true));
 echo $statisticController->ajaxLoadStatisticUser($user_data, '');
 } else {
 echo 'Invalid ID or User not logged in.';
 }
 wp_die();
 }
```